Which Internet game was the first to use UDP?
An easy way to transmit game state over the Internet is via TCP sockets.  These provide a reliable data stream, and for slow-paced games they work well.  For arcade-style games, however, a dropped packet can cause a long delay while waiting for retransmission, because data cannot be delivered out of order.
The alternative is to use UDP, which is an unreliable transport mechanism.  Packets can be lost or received out of order, but the game doesn't have to wait for stale data to arrive before receiving newer data.  These days, any Internet game for which low latency is important uses UDP to transmit updates.
To the best of my knowledge, the first game to use UDP over the Internet was Netrek, which was originally developed as client-server over TCP.  (Full disclosure: I did the UDP conversion.)  Netrek actually used a dual-socket approach, with game updates over UDP and some general state exchange over TCP, but that turned out to be a bad idea.
The game XPilot was popular around the same time, and switched from TCP to TCP+UDP to UDP, but as far as I can tell that happened afterward (the changelog I found didn't have dates for the entries).  Back in the day I was also able to find a 3D tank game that used UDP, but it was strictly LAN-based, and IIRC was using UDP for broadcasts.
The Netrek UDP network code was made available for public use in April 1992. Is anyone aware of an earlier example?  I'm specifically looking for Internet games, not LAN, for which UDP was the primary mechanism for transmission of game state updates.

Another game of similar vintage is XBlast, but it’s slightly younger, I think (1993), and I don’t know off-hand if it used UDP right from the beginning.

Friends of mine got started in the games industry in the early/mid '90s and I remember them using UDP. This was after Doom but before Quake. Doom used IPX/SPX but I guess UDP was becoming the de-facto standard already by then?

Not sure whether you'd count it or not, but I wrote a multi-machine fractal generator around 1989, that transmitted data over UDP. I originally used it on a LAN, but a couple friends who were in college at the time ran it over the internet. Not sure whether you'd consider it a "game" or not (but it certainly had no serious use) and it was never publicly released (beyond being shared between a number of friends).

Your question seems to imply that UDP-based games must have come later as an optimization. I never programmed for IPX but I understand it’s a connectionless packet-based (not stream) protocol, so a lot closer to UDP than TCP. Most early networked PC games and game programmers started with IPX. So it would seem natural to start with UDP instead of TCP when migrating to IP networks, rather than starting with TCP and then later someone suddenly being struck by genius and switching to UDP. I might be wrong.

I played DOOM and other IPX-based games back in the early '90s, but they were strictly LAN-based. You don't get many damaged or out-of-order packets on a LAN unless somebody screwed up the coaxial cable termination, so the network layers could be simpler. Internet gameplay for such games was provided by services like Mpath Interactive, TEN, and Catapult Entertainment, which came a few years later.

FYI: Nettrek appears to resemble an earlier game, "Trek," which ran on Xerox Alto minicomputers, and which used broadcast packets sent over an Ethernet network to communicate between workstations that all were connected to the same LAN segment. Trek was created in 1978—several years prior to the first use of Internet Protocol (IP). At least one of Nettrek's developers, Jef Poskanzer, had played the old Trek game at Carnegie-Mellon University before Nettrek was created.

@SolomonSlow: if you're interested in the history of Netrek (one 't'), see this page. It traces its roots to a game on the Plato system. Nettrek (two 't's) was a multiplayer game for the Mac that came out around the same time.

Thanks. I'll read it, but I never played Nettrek or any of its ancestors myself. You asked about "the first," so I thought you might be interested in knowing that there was another "Trek" game that used unreliable, "datagram" packets that were broadcast over a LAN for communication between the workstations and, which was even older than UDP. There might not be anybody who's ever even seen the old Trek game if they didn't see it at either the University of Rochester or, at Carnegie-Mellon University during the last two years of the 1970s or the first two or three years of the 1980s.
